# Regex including integers and the following symbols % , - . $

Tags: python, excel, pandas, csv

I currently am parsing a string to get the integers, and I am able to get the ints from the string. However, it isn't pulling some important punctuation (% . , - $) that needs to stay attached to the ints. How can I build a regex to address these constraints

-Any digit
-If there's a $ before the digit.
-If there's a , - . in the middle of the digits
-If there's a % after the final digit

```py
revenue_numbers = []
for cell in email_body:
    match = cell[cell.find('revenue'):cell.find('revenue')+100] #finds the word "revenue" and the 100 chars that follow and stores that string as a variable 
    rev_list = list(map(int, re.findall(r'\d+', match)))
    revenue_numbers.append(rev_list)
new_df['Revenue List'] = pd.Series(revenue_numbers)
```

Ideally, if the string were "this value is 35% and the other was 12.3 for $20 in the 2018-2019 year" then the list returned would be [35%, 12.3, $20, 2018-2019]. Right now it returns [35, 12, 3, 20, 2018, 2019]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your restrictions the solution could look like this.

```
>>> res = list(re.findall(r'\$?\d+(?:[-.,]\d+)?%?', value))
>>> res
['35%', '12.3', '$20', '2018-2019']
```

Let's have a look at the parts of the regular expression `\$?\d+(?:[-.,]\d+)?%?`.

- `\$?` is zero ore one dollar sign
- `\d+` is one ore more digits
- `(?:...)?` defines a non capturing group that might appear not or
  only once
- `[-.,]\d+` is a `-`, `.` or `,` followed by one or more digits
- `%?` is zero or one percent sign